Quando il verbo "penso" segue una frase secondaria, ci vuole il congiuntivo?
Stefano sia bravo, penso OPPURE Stefano è bravo, penso.

Puoi dire,

Stefano è bravo, penso.

Oppure

Penso che Stefano sia bravo.

